# how to make a file non -editable through vi, >, or touch ?? provided 777 permissions are already there on file

Tags: file, shell, unix, permissions, vi

I have a file, to which i have given 777 permission in unix.
Is there a way to restrict other users from editing this file from vi or touch.

Only other programs or >> can write into this file.

Comment: You could probably use ACLs to approximate this, but you'd need to provide quite a bit more detail about what specific users will be allowed which actions, and what credentials the programs that you want to have access will be running with... Otherwise, just `chmod 600 file`, and make sure that the only programs you want to update the file run as the same ID as the file owner...

Answer (score 0):

you can encrypt the file using RSA or SHA package in Unix,.
To encrypt use cmd

```
 gpg -c yourfile
```

this will prompt for password give as you like. it will create  yourfile.gpg

```
mv yourfile.gpg yourfile
```

to decrypt the file

```
 gpg yourfile
```